# Multiply each field of file

Tags: bash

I have to make a bash script wich multiply each first field of file by 10.

Example (number.csv) :

```
"1","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
"2","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
"3","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
...
```

I want to display :

```
"10","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
"20","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
"30","0","Test1","2016-03-31 15:34:50",\N,\N,"2016-03-31 15:34:58","2","2","2","1","test","3","3","3","0","1","0",\N,"1","0","0",\N,\N,"0","0","0","0","8","0","0","0","0"
...
```

How can i do this ?
Thank you

Comment: You may want to show the script you have so far so as to narrow down the number of possible answers in an attempt to get the question out of "On Hold".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use awk or Perl and its [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV), you can try a simple

```
sed 's/",/0",/'
```

Comment: It works, thanks you very much !

Comment: And if i want to multiply only the second field ?

Comment: I find the solution : awk -F , -v OFS=, '$2*=10 {print "\""$1"\""",""\""$2"\""",""\""$3"\""",""\""$4"\""}' number.csv